# xmlstarlet update not working in case of namespace defined in xml

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.abc.def" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>JoinTMA</name>
</widget>
```

I want to update the value of version="1.0.0" to version="2.0.0"

I tried with the following command on macOS

```
xml ed -N x="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" -u "/widget[@version='1.0.0']/@version" -v "2.0.0" fileName
```

But it did not update the version number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that your XML has *default namespace* :

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
```

Therefore, `widget` and `name` elements are implicitly in that namespace. You have declared prefix `x` mapped to the default namespace URI, so you only need to use that prefix to reference `widget` in your XPath :

```
xml ed -N x="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" -u "/x:widget[@version='1.0.0']/@version" -v "2.0.0" fileName
                                                ^use the prefix
```

Comment: I just used "//x:widget[@version='1.0.0']/@version" in stead of "/x:widget[@version='1.0.0']/@version" and its working fine now. Thanks.